# How to open another class containing a frame from the main class

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a small window which only contains a label and 2 buttons in the first class and a second which contains the gui in another class. how can I close the small window and start the gui after i made my choice? I tried to just run the main method from the gui but I don't really know what to fill in for String args[]...

```
gui.main(??);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go by two ways:

`Way 1`: Have a constructor in class2 and call it from your class1 like.

```
new Class2Name();    //Class2Name() is a constructor of class2
```

`Way 2`: For your current approach you can use below code:

```
new Class2Name().main(null);    //null if you don't want to pass any parameter
```

**Update1**

To close the frame:

```
frameName.dispose();  //Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its subcomponents, and all of its owned children.
```

To hide the frame:

```
frameName.setVisible(false);  //Shows or hides Window
```

Comment: thank, the second way is working! How can I now close the first frame afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly your question. You're saying that from the first window, whenever you click a button, you want to open another gui according to the button clicked, right?

If so you have to declare the second gui from your buttons of the first class and pass a parameter to the constructor of the second class. For example: for button 1 you do this:

```
//This part should be at the top of your class
String param = "";

//this part should be in your button
secondClass second = new secondClass();
second.show()
```